# postgres how to compare jsonb array and array

Tags: postgresql

This my jonb data

```
contact:{
    "name": "Jonh",
    "country": ["USA", "UK"],
  }
```

And my query:

```
SELECT * FROM public.product where contact -> 'country' = ARRAY['USA','UK'];
```

Executed the query and got this `ERROR:  operator does not exist: jsonb = text[]`
So how do I fix this error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to compare it with a JSONB array:

```
select *
from product
where contact -> 'country' = '["USA","UK"]'::jsonb;
```

But this depends on the order of the elements in the array. If you want to test all keys regardless of the order, the `?&` operator might be better:

```
where contact -> 'country' ?& array['UK','USA']
```

That would however also return rows that contain additional elements in the array. If you need to match all elements exactly regardless of the order you could use the `@>` operator twice:

```
where contact -> 'country' @> '["USA","UK"]'::jsonb
  and contact -> 'country' <@ '["USA","UK"]'::jsonb
```

Comment: Thank you, this I want. One more thing, where I can read more about ?& operator.

Comment: @jimmy: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html

Answer (score 0):

Use `to_jsonb()`:

```
SELECT (('{"a": ["x","y","z"]}'::jsonb)->'a') = to_jsonb(array['x','y','z']);
```

^^ Returns true.